# How to create a stream in /sys that acts like an infinite file (FIFO)

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm working on a linux module and I'm looking for ways to provide a FIFO end to userspace to read from.
I can find API to create the kfifo and API such as the use of `__ATTR()` but I can't find for an infinite stream. Which make one wonder if this be done on `/sys`?

In my plan, the kfifo would be used to queue events the userspace, where a process that has `open`ed can read block on and read byte by byte for each event.

I'm working on a driver for extra keyboard buttons. The driver listens for acpi events and updates the state of LEDs and also is supposed to warn listeners about the change (e.g. special keypresses such as a "keyboard light change color" event).
For the change color event example, the driver would provide 1 byte specifying the current color code in use.

Alternatively, some sort of "reverse`ioctl`" I don't know about would also solve this issue but, as far as I know, there's no such thing.

I already tried to check for "cousins" of `__ATTR()` such as `__ATTR_PREALLOC` and `__BIN_ATTR` but none seem to be compatible with keeping the fd open to keep receiving updates or show any ways to safely block the caller.

Comment: sysfs is a filesystem for exporting **information** about the kernel: which attribute has which value. For arbitrary files use other filesystems: debugfs, procfs. They allow to create a file with `file_operations`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev There's no process, so no procfs. It's not debugging so I suppose it's not debugfs. What options are there for streams? Maybe `/dev`? I just need to know what API is there to make this objective. What I can find is for filesystems in devfs which is way beyond what I'm after.

Comment: Information about *processes* is not the only information provided by procfs, so you could use procfs for your purposes too. If you think about your file as a **device**, then placing it under `/dev` is good too. Such files are known as "character devices".

Comment: @Tsyvarev Do you know where can I find the API to make a symlink in `/sys`? I know only sys_symlink (https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/syscalls.h#L1091) but the file states it's deprecated. I'm having a hard time finding what its replacement is

Comment: Like any other `sys_`-prefixed function, `sys_symlink` is the implementation of a **system call** `symlink`. This system call is able to create a symlink in any filesystem.. while a filesystem allows this. `/sys` is a special filesystem, which doesn't allow a user to create files/directories in it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev however, linux modules can create symlinks inside `/sys`. Do you know the function for that?

Comment: Probably, this is [class_compat_create_link](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/C/ident/class_compat_create_link). But as far as I understand, it can only create symlinks to a file under `/sys`.

Comment: found it: [sysfs_create_link](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/sysfs/symlink.c#L89). Thank you. Thanks to that lead, I found the one I needed.